# cant set a state inside function (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, state

Learning by coding, here i have simple graph, where are different datas such as current, all and filtered data, first code works fine, but i wanted to setState so i changed code a little (second code), if i uncomment 'setTest' it give 'Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.' is there a fix to this or should i somehow use useEffect?
and another question is why should i call function 'kk()', and not just reference to it 'kk' because when i use reference it give error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined' but when calling function it wont give error, but then i have used reference to function without problem 'onClickNode={onClickNode}' .

1:

```js
import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";
<Graph data={ 
hideData ? 
curentData ? allData : filteredData 
: allData } 
      onClickNode={onClickNode}


/>
```

2:

```js
 import { Graph } from "react-d3-graph";
 const [test, setTest] = useState<any>("testData1");
 
  const kk = () => {
   // setTest("testData2")
    return curentData ? allData : filteredData;
  };

 
 <Graph
          data={hideData ? kk() : allData}   onClickNode={onClickNode}

        />
```

English is not my mother language so could be mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call a state changing function within your rendering logic without some sort of condition. Without a condition to prevent a state change results in an infinite loop as you are seeing.

One option you can try is call `setTest("testData2")` on a particular user action, like this:

```
  const [test, setTest] = useState<any>("testData1");
 
  const kk = () => {
    return curentData ? allData : filteredData;
  };
  
  const onClickNode = () => {
    // Handle other click logic...
    setTest("testData2");
  };
  
  <Graph data={hideData ? kk() : allData} onClickNode={onClickNode} />
```

But without seeing more of that code, that option may not make sense for you.

Another option would be to check the value of `test` before calling `setTest("testData2")`, like this:

```
  const [test, setTest] = useState<any>("testData1");
  
  const kk = () => {
    if (test !== "testData2") {
      setTest("testData2");
    }
    return curentData ? allData : filteredData;
  };
 
  <Graph data={hideData ? kk() : allData} onClickNode={onClickNode} />
```

Comment: Your "another option" is still bad even though it won't cause infinite rerenders. There is zero reason to perform any side effects - including updating state - as part of rendering. Such things should be done perhaps in a `useEffect` callback, but really I don't know what the OP should do because they don't explain anything about how they want their component to behave.